# NLTK parsing recursion error with custom grammar

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

The following codes prints nothing out even though the `RecursiveDescentParser` is being created. What's my problem? Am I defining the grammar incorrectly?

```
sent = ["I'm", 'attracted', 'by', 'the', 'touching', 'story']
grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
    S -> NP | VP
    NP -> "I'm" | Det Adj N
    VP -> V P
   
    V -> 'attracted'
    P -> 'by'
    Det -> 'the'
    Adj -> 'touching'
    N -> 'story'
   """)

rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)
for tree in rd_parser.parse(sent):
    print(tree)
```